# Plot3D plotting serrated edge

Tags: plotting, graphics, computational-geometry, rendering

I want to plot the upper casket of a sphere in 3D using its parametrisation as $s(x,y) = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. Although this show be straight forward with Plot3D, I am running into an issue I find very funny.

As you might see in the picture below, when rendering the upper casket, a serrated pattern appears. Recall that increasing the value of PlotPoints provides a better result, yet a serrated pattern keeps appearing.

Does anyone know why this happens and how could it be avoided?

Thank you all in advance!
[image]

Comment: Please post your code instead of only pictures.

Comment: The code appears too: it is just right above each picture.

Comment: But the we  can't copy the code from the pictures.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. Sorry, I should've thought of that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please post plain text code next time to eliminate having to type it from the image and making error.

You can play with `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints` to improve the plot. For example

```
s[x_, y_] := Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]
Plot3D[s[x, y], Element[{x, y}, Disk[{0, 0}]], 
    MaxRecursion -> 4, (*try this option*)
    PlotPoints -> 40   (*and this option*)
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Help for `MaxRecursion`  says `Refine the surface where it changes quickly`
You can also add `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` but this did not seem to help as much as `MaxRecursion` but will not hurt to use it.

**Update**

Moo's comment below is better and faster:

```
Plot3D[s[x, y], Element[{x, y}, Disk[{0, 0}]], Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update 2**

cvgmt comment below gets better

```
Plot3D[s[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Maybe Plot3D[s[x, y], Element[{x, y}, Disk[{0, 0}]], Exclusions -> None]

Comment: @Moo nice one. I did not think of trying it. too many options, too little time. Feel free to post it as answer. Your solution is better and faster.

Comment: No worries - add that as an update to your answer. In both cases, look at the artifact at $0$.

Comment: `Plot3D[s[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> None]` get better.

Comment: @Nasser: It is interesting that if you look at the boundary closely (between zero and one), you can see artifacts of the original issue - looks like white streaks. Can this be considered a bug?

Comment: Thank you both!! It does definitely get better, but yes, it still looks somewhat wavely. Funny stuff, isn't it?

Comment: @juanzaragoza yes, I noticed that also. Try to play with the two options I used in my answer in addition to use the cvgmt command to see if the small wavey things near the edges go away.

Comment: But, still, have you got any idea why this happens? Since the sourcecode for how this Plot3D works is not public and my experience is limited regarding this topics, I cannot find a reason why it plots it that way.

Comment: @juanzaragoza sorry, I do not know. It might be due to some numerical artifact.